# c# why my serial port closed is not close the port?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have problem in `serialport.close`.

```
Port opened at 9/21/2016 10:58:32 AM
Port communication has been closed 9/21/2016 10:58:48 AM
Access to the port 'COM3' is denied.
```

At the beginning I click connect button, and the second I click disconnect button which inside button I fill the `close.port` code. but when I click connect again the status is denied. This is my code :

```
public void ClosePort()
{
    if (comPort.IsOpen)
    {
        //e.Cancel = true; //cancel the fom closing
        Thread CloseDown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CloseSerialOnExit)); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
        CloseDown.Start(); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
        DisplayData(MessageType.Error, "Port communication has been closed" + " " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
    }
}

private void CloseSerialOnExit()
{
    try
    {
        comPort.Close(); //close the serial port
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //catch any serial port closing error messages
    }
    BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(NowClose)); //now close back in the main thread
}

private void NowClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comPort.Close(); //now close the form
}

public void BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
{ 

}
```

This code is showing message success to close but when click connect again access denied, when I check in task manager the program still running when we are click the exit button. why close port not response? is it way to fix that? or using another method? I hope suggestion and really big thanks for answer and solution.

Comment: You don't actually wait it to be closed, you just throw it to another thread and forget it. Not the way to do it.

Comment: so how the ritght way to close port? if i only using the usually using serialport.closed that's not work